# Cannot verify JWT token

Tags: express, jwt, nestjs

I am using NestJS and its JWT package based on jsonwebtoken. The generated token is always being invalid, and I am getting a 500 - Internal Server Error.
What might be the problem?

My login function in the AuthService:

```
  async login(email: string, password: string, isAdmin?: boolean, isVIP?: boolean){
    let user = await this.usersService.findByEmail(email);
    if(!user){
      throw new NotFoundException('No user with this email could be found.');
    }
    const isEqual = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if(!isEqual){
      throw new BadRequestException('Email and password do not match');
    }
    const secret = 'secretkey';
    const payload = {email: user.email, userId: user._id.toString()}
    const token = this.jwtService.sign(payload, {secret, expiresIn: '1h'});
    return [email, isAdmin, isVIP, token];
  }
```

My verification logic in the AuthGuard
`

```
import { BadRequestException, CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Inject } from "@nestjs/common";
import { JwtService } from "@nestjs/jwt/dist";
import { JwtConfigService } from "src/config/jwtconfig.service";

export class JwtAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(@Inject(JwtService) private jwtService: JwtService){}
    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

        const authHeader = request.get('Authorization');
        if (!authHeader) {
            throw new BadRequestException('Not authorized');
        }
    const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    let decodedToken;
    try {
        decodedToken = this.jwtService.verify(token, {secret: 'secretkey'});
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error('Cannot verify token.')
    }
    if(!decodedToken){
        throw new BadRequestException('Not authenticated')
    }
  request.userId = decodedToken.userId;
  console.log({decodedToken, token});
  return request.userId;
};
}
```

`My current JWT setup in the UsersModule imports (I have no AuthModule); I tried all the other configurations in the official docs, too.`

```
JwtModule.register({
   secret: 'secretkey',
   publicKey: '...',
   privateKey: '...',
   secretOrKeyProvider: (
     requestType: JwtSecretRequestType,
     tokenOrPayload: string | Object | Buffer,
     verifyOrSignOrOptions?: jwt.VerifyOptions | jwt.SignOptions
   ) => {
     switch (requestType) {
       case JwtSecretRequestType.SIGN:
         return 'privateKey';
       case JwtSecretRequestType.VERIFY:
         return 'publicKey';
       default:
         return 'secretkey';
     }
   },
 })
```

`

My jwtconfig.ts, which I don't think is being used:
`

```
import { JwtOptionsFactory, JwtModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/jwt'

export class JwtConfigService implements JwtOptionsFactory {
    createJwtOptions(): JwtModuleOptions {
      return {
        secret: 'secretkey'
      };
    }
  }
```

`

Comment: I don't see any debugging attempts. What's the exact value of token in the call to jwtService.verify()? You also did not even evaluate err but just throw an error and wonder about the result.

Comment: My token is for example: My token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImNsaWVudDIwMDBAaG90bWFpbC5jb20iLCJ1c2VySWQiOiI2MzgyNTNlMTQ0ZDIzOGU3NDA2MDFkMDEiLCJpYXQiOjE2Njk1MzM4NTAsImV4cCI6MTY2OTUzNzQ1MH0.EwqcTNOO1Wxw-Ga0mfuUHmdsdGA52LGq3fTT_4jHe7A; the payload is written in the login function. The verified token is always being undefined.  I threw an error as this code has been taken from Academind's Nodejs course and I'm trying to adapt it to Nest, as we have been advised not to use passport. This is not even my second month of "advanced" programming so sorry for being a noob. @jps

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by switching my guard to a middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the secret when registering the Jwt service globally. And also passing the secret when verifying the token. Remove passing the secret again when verifying.

```
decodedToken = this.jwtService.verify(token, {secret: 'secretkey'});
```

Like this.

```
decodedToken = this.jwtService.verify(token);
```